# TypeError: It would appear that nargs is set to conflict with the composite type arity

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, oop, python-click

I wrote this short little program as an effort to teach myself object oriented design in Python. But I am currently getting a very confusing error.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 97, in <module>
  cli()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 716, in __call__
  return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 695, in main
  with self.make_context(prog_name, args, **extra) as ctx:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 620, in make_context
  self.parse_args(ctx, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 874, in parse_args
  value, args = param.handle_parse_result(ctx, opts, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1390, in handle_parse_result
  value = self.full_process_value(ctx, value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1675, in full_process_value
  return Parameter.full_process_value(self, ctx, value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1359, in full_process_value
  value = self.process_value(ctx, value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1349, in process_value
  return self.type_cast_value(ctx, value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1332, in type_cast_value
  return self.type(value or (), self, ctx)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\click\types.py", line 38, in __call__
  return self.convert(value, param, ctx)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\click\types.py", line 472, in convert
  raise TypeError('It would appear that nargs is set to conflict '
  TypeError: It would appear that nargs is set to conflict with the composite type arity.
```

This error is being raised by my [click](http://click.pocoo.org/6/) based CLI. Which is odd because one of the options that is raising the error doesn't have any arguments.

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import click
import json
import glob
import os

def prompt(question):
    val = raw_input(question + ' > ')
    return val

def mkdir(path):
    if not os.path.isdir(str(path)):
            os.mkdir(str(path))
    return str(path)


class Profile(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age, weight, job, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.weight = weight
        self.job = job
        self.salary = salary

        self.data = { 'name' : '',
                      'age' : '',
                      'weight' : '',
                      'job': '',
                      'salary' : ''
                     }

    def new_profile(self, name, age, job, weight, salary, fname):
        self.data['name'] = name
        self.data['age'] = age
        self.data['job'] = job
        self.data['weight'] = weight
        self.data['salary'] = salary
        self.fname = fname

        self.dirname = mkdir('.profiles\\')

        with open(str(self.dirname) + str(self.fname) + '.json', 'w') as self.profile:
            json.dump(self.data, self.profile)

        print 'Profile saved!'


    def list_profile(self):
        print glob.glob('.profiles/*.json')

    def print_profile(self, fname):
        try:
            self.fname = fname

            with open('.profiles\\' + str(self.fname) + '.json') as data_file:
                self.profile = json.load(data_file)

            self.name = self.profile['name']
            self.age = self.profile['age']
            self.weight = self.profile['weight']
            self.job = self.profile['job']
            self.salary = self.profile['salary']

            print 'name: {}\nage: {}\nweight: {}\noccupation: {}\nsalary: {}'.format(self.name, self.age, self.weight, self.job, self.salary)

        except IOError:
            print 'File not found'

@click.command(options_metavar='<options>')
@click.option('--new_profile', '-n',
              nargs=6,
              type=click.Tuple([str, str, str, str, str, str]),
              metavar='<name, age, occupation, weight, salary, filename>',
              help='Creates a new profile')
@click.option('--list_profile', '-l',
              is_flag=True,
              help='Lists all profiles that currently exist')
@click.option('--print_profile', '-p',
              type=(str),
              metavar='<profile name>',
              help = 'prints data from a saved profile')
def cli(new_profile, list_profile, print_profile):
    profile = Profile('', '', '', '', '')

    if new_profile:
        profile.new_profile(new_profile[0], new_profile[1], new_profile[2], new_profile[3], new_profile[4], new_profile[5]) # name, age, job, weight, salary, fname
    elif list_profile:
        profile.list_profile()
    elif print_profile:
        profile.print_profile(print_profile)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

I have been struggling with this traceback for about a day now with no result. Any suggestions? Thanks!

EDIT: I sort of fixed it, but I created a logic error in the process.

```
default=(None, None, None, None, None, None))
```

I added this argument to the click option new_profile. But when you use any other argument it just runs

```
Profile.new_profile(None, None None, None, None None)
```

thus creating a new file called `none.json` in `.profile` with all values being null. So I guess I technically solved *THIS* problem but I created an even bigger one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can fix this.

**Do not use `click.Tuple`**

`Tuple` is intended for a multiple valued argument of non-uniform type.  Since you are using 6 strings, this can be done more simply with:

```
@click.option('--new_profile', '-n',
              nargs=6,
              type=str,
              ....
```

**Use `click.Tuple` with a default**

As you discovered you can use a `click.Tuple` if you specify a default.

```
@click.option('--new_profile', '-n',
              default=[None] * 6,
              type=click.Tuple([str, str, str, str, str, str]),
              ....
```

Then you can qualify that you did not get the default like:

```
if new_profile and None not in new_profile:
    # create a new profile
    ....
```

Comment: this is super helpful